# RN ios build with Xcode: Why I am getting so many warnings (buildtime)?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I build an app with React Native (v 0.64). And I made up iOS build using Xcode (version 12.3). The app gets build and works without any crash or bug - on simulator and also on real iPhone (latest iOS versions 14.3).

Despite working everything fine, I get during buildtime a LOT of warnings (196). Mostly they are of a two kinds- Nullability issue or Deprecations.

I got all my node modules updated to latest versions and I think the podfile is okay too. But the warnings appear at almost every library I am using, so it makes me assume that I am missing some more general point (maybe wrong podfile or something like that). What I am missing?

I am about to publish on App store in next days (after working several weeks on this project) and this makes me worried so much. I attach screen from the Xcode of mentioned errors (part of those).

[image]

Comment: Most of them look harmless to me

Comment: Thx for your feedback. Also I got folly Semantic issue- "code will never be executed" dynamic.cpp...

Comment: "code will never be executed" that's fine... just an extra couple bytes, no difference really

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback ! :)